# If $\{a,b,c,d,e\}\subset[0,1]$ so $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{1+a+b}\leq\frac{5}{1+2\sqrt[5]{abcde}}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $\{a,b,c,d,e\}\subset[0,1]$. Prove that:
$$\frac{1}{1+a+b}+\frac{1}{1+b+c}+\frac{1}{1+c+d}+\frac{1}{1+d+e}+\frac{1}{1+e+a}\leq\frac{5}{1+2\sqrt[5]{abcde}}$$
I tried C-S, convexity and more, but without success.

Comment: Funny question: where do you get these hard inequalities?

Comment: @Charter It's not mine. I noted this inequality a few years ago.

Comment: I was doing a little research on google and I think you may try to use the mixing variable method or something like that.

Comment: I'm surprised that you didn't get a result from convexity here. It looks a natural for it. You can apply Jensen's inequality to any pair of curves whose difference is convex. Problem is finding the right ones :)

Answer (score 4):

Here are two cases.

**Case 1: (cyclically) ${a b} < \frac14$ .**

Observe $a+b \ge 2 \sqrt{a b}$ by AM-GM, likewise for the other terms. So it is enough to prove

$$
\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{1 +2 \sqrt{a b}} \leq\frac{5}{1+2\sqrt[5]{abcde}}
$$
Let $2 \sqrt{a b} = x$, $2 \sqrt{b c} = y$, etc.
Then we need
$$
\frac 15 \, \sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{1 +x} \leq\frac{1}{1+ \sqrt[5]{\prod_{cyc}x}}
$$
Consider the function 
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{1 +e^z}
$$
We have 
$$
f''(z) = \frac{e^z (e^z -1)}{(1+e^z)^3}
$$
so for $z < 0$ we have that $f''(z) < 0$ and hence $f(z)$ is strictly concave. Hence by Jensen,
$$
\frac 15 \, \sum_{cyc} f(z_i) \leq f(\frac 15 \, \sum_{cyc} z_i)
$$
Now apply $e^{z_i} = x$ cyclically. This establishes the inequality for $z < 0$, i.e. when  all $x = 2 \sqrt{ab} < 1$.

**Case 2: (cyclically) $a + b \leq 1$ .**

I am grateful for a comment by  Hugh Denoncourt  which lead to this case.

Define a vector $(w,z)$. Consider the function 
$$
f(w,z) = - \frac{1}{1 +e^z + e^w}
$$
which is the negative of the function under consideration, so we are looking for convexity.
We have the second partial derivative:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f(w,z)}{\partial w^2} = \frac{e^w (1 +e^z - e^w)}{(1+e^z+e^w)^3}
$$
and for $z$ likewise.
We also have the Hessian of this function:
$$
H = \frac{e^z e^w (1 -e^z - e^w)}{(1+e^z+e^w)^5}
$$
so for $e^z + e^w < 1$ we have that $H > 0$ and hence $f(w,z)$ is strictly convex. Hence by Jensen's inequality for vector-valued functions,
$$
\frac 15 \, \sum_{cyc} f(w_i,z_i) \geq f(\frac 15 \, \sum_{cyc} (w_i,z_i))
$$
Now apply $e^{z_i} = a$ and $e^{w_i} = b$ cyclically. This establishes the inequality for all $a+b<1$. However, this will not solve the case fully for $0 \leq a,b \leq 1$.

Comment: If it were not the Hessian, but positivity of the second partial derivatives, this would always be given for $0 \leq a,b \leq 1$. Do we need the Hessian?

Comment: This seems like it's the right direction. I suspect the concavity of $f(x,y) = 1 / (1 + e^x + e^y)$ for $0 < e^x \leq 1$ and $0 < e^y \leq 1$ establishes the full result. However, the concavity details are messier than those for $f(z) = 1 / (1 + e^z)$.

Comment: It looks like case 1 works only if all the adjacent cyclic pairs are $ab<\frac{1}{4}$ and case 2 works only if all the cyclic pairs are $a+b>1$. What about the case where some fall into case 1 and some — into case 2?

Comment: @ElThor I corrected case 2: case 2 doesn't fix the deficiencies of case 1 yet.

Comment: In retrospect (from your Hessian determinant), nothing new comes from $1/(1 + e^x + e^y)$ that you can't get just from $1/(1 + e^z)$. If $a + b \leq 1$ for all of the cyclically adjacent variables, we have $\frac{1}{5} \sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{1 + a_i + b_i} \leq \frac{1}{1 + \prod_{cyc} \sqrt[5]{a_i + b_i}} \leq \frac{1}{1 + \prod_{cyc} \sqrt[5]{2 \sqrt{a_i b_i}}} = \frac{1}{1 + 2\sqrt[5]{abcde}}$ with the last inequality coming from AM-GM and the initial one coming from concavity of $1/(1 + e^z)$ with each $a_i + b_i$ substituted for $e^z$.

Comment: @HughDenoncourt  I was expanding on your suggestion, but: yes, it didn't bring the full solution. Further, $a + b <1$ covers less cases then the first calcuation where $ab < 1/4$.

Comment: @Andreas: True, $ab \leq 1/4$ (for all cyclically adjacent variables) is a better partial result.

Comment: @Andreas +25 is not mine. I don't understand why are taken 25 points from my 50  bounty's points? I don't agree with this thing. I think the starting inequality is still unsolved.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Help me please.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg It's an automatic assignment, explained in the bounty FAQs.